# Laravel explicit route mode binding not working in some cases?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I am using Laravel 8 and explicit route mode binding in my project to call an product under the `slug` instead of the `id`. I have products, posts and etc, which are all using explicit route mode binding with the `slug` in the database instead of the `id`.

What really confuses me is that the explicit route mode binding is working everywhere but not with `products`. Here is my RouteServiceProvider:

```
// Change route for product from $id to $slug
Route::bind('product', function ($value) {
    return Product::where('slug', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});

// Change route for user from $id to $name
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
    return User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});

// Change route for product from $id to $slug
Route::bind('post', function ($value) {
    return Post::where('slug', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

Here are some example `routes` for a `user`, a `product` and a `post`:

```
works:      Route::get('/product/{productType}/{product}', ['as' => 'product.show', 'uses' => 'ProductController@show']);     
404 error:  Route::post('product/{product}/like', ['as' => 'product.like', 'uses' => 'LikeController@likeProduct']);          
404 error:  Route::post('product/{product}/dislike', ['as' => 'product.dislike', 'uses' => 'LikeController@dislikeProduct']); 
404 error:  Route::post('product/{product}/mark', ['as' => 'product.mark', 'uses' => 'ProductController@markProduct']);

works:      Route::get('user/{user}', ['as' => 'user.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);
works:      Route::post('user/{user}/update/password', ['as' => 'user.password.change', 'uses' => 'UserController@updatePassword']);

works:      Route::get('/blog/{postCategory}/{post}', ['as' => 'post.show', 'uses' => 'PostController@show']);
```

When I do a `dd` for the `value` in the RouteServiceProvider for `user`, `product` and `post` I can figure out what's the problem here. All `values` do dump the actual `slug` of the resource.  Even the `get` request for a product is the actual `slug`. However, when performing an `post` request for a `product`, I always get the end of the `url` as value. Of course this leads to a `404`.

For example the route `product/{product}/mark` with an `post` requests does dump `mark` as `value` and not the `slug` of the product... why is that? All other `post` requests work fine!

I also tried switch a route from a `post` method to a `get` method but same result here... also an `404` error and  I get `mark` as `value` again...

Can anybody explain whats the problem here and why it is not working?

When I change `product/{product}/mark` to `produkt/{product}/mark` it is working. But why? and why is '/product/{productType}/{product}' working? That is really strange..

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: if `product/{productType}/{product}` is before `product/{product}/like|dislike|mark` then there would be a conflict right?

Comment: btw, you know you can define what field to use with implicit bindings?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, this route `product/{productType}/{product}` is the first route in my web.php file. But why does this cause a conflict?

Comment: @lagbox how can I do this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-key

Comment: Yes, I am using this solution now. Just answered myself

Answer (score 0):

I have now removed my changes in the `RouteServiceProvider` and I am using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-key) function which is provided since Laravel 8. Problem solved... I don't know what the problem was..

Comment: Honestly I don't know why this solved the problem. For example if you have a product with slug `like` and try to access `product/a-type/like` how would this use the correct route instead of doing `product/{product}/like`

Comment: @apokryfos voodoo